# How to pivot in bigQuery using PIVOT?

Tags: google-bigquery, procedural

I am trying to pull rows as columns in bigquery.
This is how my data looks like now:
[image]

This is how I want my data to look like:
[image]

PS: While I have shown only 3 values in column `SUB_CLASS_DESC` actual count is in 100s. Hence, I am looking to use Procedural language as per documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language). I followed the example shared [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/pivot-in-bigquery-4eefde28b3be) in towardsdatascience.com and wrote below code, but unfortunately that doesn't work:

```
DECLARE DEPT_CLASS_SUB_CLASS STRING;
SET DEPT_CLASS_SUB_CLASS = (SELECT CONCAT('("', STRING_AGG(DISTINCT DEPT_CLASS_SUB_CLASS, '", "'), '")')
FROM `analytics-mkt-cleanroom.Workspace.HS_AF_SG_R12_800K_SAMPLE_SALES_11_TEST`
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `analytics-mkt-cleanroom.Workspace.HS_AF_SG_R12_800K_SAMPLE_SALES_PIVOTED_12_TEST` AS 
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT HH_ID,DEPT_CLASS_SUB_CLASS,SALE_AMT 
FROM `analytics-mkt-cleanroom.Workspace.HS_AF_SG_R12_800K_SAMPLE_SALES_11_TEST`
)
PIVOT
(SUM(SALE_AMT)
,FOR DEPT_CLASS_SUB_CLASS IN %s
)""",DEPT_CLASS_SUB_CLASS);
```

Error I am getting:
[image]

Error message suggests to declare before the execute block, and I am doing exactly that, but I don't understand why the error still persists.
I tried declaring variables DEPT_CLASS_SUB_CLASS in different ways but not successful yet. Could anyone please point out where I might be making the mistake.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate (select '''
  select *
  from your_table
  pivot (any_value(sale_amt) for replace(sub_class_desc, ' ', '_') in (''' || list || '''))
  '''
  from (
    select string_agg(distinct "'" || replace(sub_class_desc, ' ', '_') || "'") list
    from your_table
  )
)
```

if applied to dummy data as in  your question - output is

[image]

> How can I save these results into a new pivoted table? Specifically where can I put my CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE?

```
execute immediate (select '''
  create or replace table `your_project.your_dataset.pivot_table` as 
  select *
  from your_table
  pivot (any_value(sale_amt) for replace(sub_class_desc, ' ', '_') in (''' || list || '''))
  '''
  from (
    select string_agg(distinct "'" || replace(sub_class_desc, ' ', '_') || "'") list
    from your_table
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How can I save these results into a new pivoted table? Specifically where can I put my `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` ?

Comment: Also - Is there a way to alphabetically arrange the columns in the results ?

Comment: if you have new or follow up question - please post it and we will  help you further :o)

Comment: Thanks. I have asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72134065/how-to-arrange-bigquery-results-columns-alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

1. `DEPT_CLASS_SUB_CLASS` variable should be placed before any other statement, not just before an execute block being referenced.
   From your error message, you seems to declare a variable at [411:1] which means at 411 line. Kindly move it to the top of your script at line 1 and test it again.
2. you have kind of a PIVOTing problem. I wrote down some test query which do PIVOTing and list columns in an alphabetical order at the same time.

```sql
DECLARE sample_data ARRAY<STRUCT<HH_ID STRING, SUB_CLASS_DESC STRING, SALE_AMT FLOAT64>> DEFAULT [
  ('HHH_001', 'K&B FIXTURE/PLUMBING', 139.),
  ('HHH_001', 'PULLDOWN KITCHEN FAUCETS', 129.),
  ('HHH_001', 'TUBULAR REPAIR & REPLACE', 0.)
];

CREATE TEMP TABLE data AS
  SELECT r.* REPLACE(TRANSLATE(SUB_CLASS_DESC, ' &/', '___') AS SUB_CLASS_DESC)
    FROM UNNEST(sample_data) r
;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT ("""
  SELECT * 
    FROM data  
   PIVOT (SUM(SALE_AMT) AS sale_amt FOR SUB_CLASS_DESC IN ('%s'));
""", (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT SUB_CLASS_DESC, "','"  ORDER BY SUB_CLASS_DESC ASC) FROM data)
);
```

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0km67.png)