# How to arrange Bigquery results columns alphabetically?

Tags: google-bigquery

I wanted to rearrange the columns of a Bigquery SQL result set. I couldn't find any documentation that would allow me to do so. While it is possible to do it manually, I have 1005 columns with different names that I want to organize.

What I have:
[image]

What I'd like to rearrange columns to:
[image]

Comment: based on your original/previous post - I think you are asking wrong question. read [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/507852)

Answer (score 1):

Below answer is based on knowing your real case and using same data sample (see [How to pivot in bigQuery using PIVOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72103324/5221944))

```
execute immediate (select '''
  create or replace table `temp.pivot_table` as 
  select *
  from your_table
  pivot (any_value(sale_amt) for replace(sub_class_desc, ' ', '_') in (''' || list || '''))
  '''
  from (
    select string_agg("'" || replace(sub_class_desc, ' ', '_') || "'", ',' order by sub_class_desc) list
    from (select distinct sub_class_desc from your_table)
  )
);
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An approach is use the [`INFORMMATION_SCHEMA`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) to list columns from a table and then the [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) to execute a dynamic SQL:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(
  CONCAT(
    "SELECT ", 
    (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name ORDER BY column_name ASC)
      FROM project_id.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE table_name = 'table'
    ), 
    " FROM `project_id.dataset.table`"
  )
)
```